# Visual Studio 2022- How to silence warning CS8604

Tags: visual-studio-2022

As the title says.

Not per line.
Not per file.
Not per project.

I want this warning gone forever.

Comment: Compiler make warnings for a reason. It's better to understand it than just ignore

Comment: For what reason?  I get that null references can be buggy, and throw errors, but what is the alternative, catch the exception and rethrow?  Put a handler in for the null exception and silently ignore.  Stupid in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

CS8604 is "*Possible null reference argument for parameter*".

If you need **just suppress this warning** you can set this rule severity to 'silent' or 'none' from the error list as described in [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/use-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2022#set-rule-severity-from-the-error-list-window):

1. After a violation occurs, right-click the diagnostic entry in the error list.
2. From the context menu, select Set severity.
3. From there, choose one of the severity options (in this case - 'none' or 'silent')

Visual Studio adds an entry to the EditorConfig file to configure the rule to the requested level.

**If we are talking about code**, fixing that warning involves one of four techniques (corresponding to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings#possible-null-assigned-to-a-nonnullable-reference)):

- Change the left side of the assignment to a nullable type. This
  action may introduce new warnings when you dereference that variable.
- Provide a null-check before the assignment.
- Annotate the API that produces the right-hand side of the assignment.
- Add the null forgiving operator to the right-hand side of the assignment.